# HTML to PDF with absolute positioning

Tags: php, css, tcpdf, mpdf, html2pdf

I need to generate a PDF, which the user will print on a *Specific form*, so I have positioned the data in a way that the form will be filled in a proper way after printing.

As of now I have used **absolute positioning** like

```
<div class="page_container">
    <div class="first_name">
       John Smith
    </div>
</div>
```

The style is

```
.page_container {
    position:relative;
}

.page_container .first_name {
    position:absolute;
    left:50px;
    top:110px;
}
```

But I could not achieve the positioning in the generated PDF. I have tried with **TCPDF and mPDF** so far.

My question would be, is there any html to **pdf library** available to support the above code, else what could be the **best alternative** to achieve my requirement.

Additional Info: I develop this on Symfony2, I am also ready to use a core php library.

Comment: So what did you achieve? Also when you say specific form do you mean pre-printed?

Comment: I can successfully generate a `pdf`. But `first_name` was not aligned as specified. And Yes, it is a pre-printed application form.

Comment: You are on a hiding to nothing with this. Usual approach is something like IText or other pdf creator and overlay the data in the pdf. ie use the pre-printed pdf as a template and edit it adding the data.